# Como travar uma pagina responsiva em portrait(retrato)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, navegador-de-internet, mobile

Existe alguma solução para exibir a página web sempre em portrait(retrato) em dispositivos móveis, mesmo se o usuário girar para o modo landscape(paisagem)? Ou seja, deixar travado sempre em portrait.

Answer (score 4):

Até o presente momento (e até onde sei) não é possível realizar esta mecânica *nativamente*. Existe uma proposta WebAPI chamada [Screen.LockOrientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen.lockOrientation) que atenderia este requisito, travando o browser em rotações específicas.

Em teoria esse comportamento pode ser emulado via [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) e a propriedade CSS [Transform](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

A propriedade a ser verificada via media queries é a *orientation*, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) { 
    #content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* IE */
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Opera */
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    /* Internet Explorer */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

    /* final spec */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode tentar rodar o corpo da sua pagina ou determinada div que envolve, no evento "orientationchange" utilizando jquery:

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(){
    var orientation = window.orientation;
    var new_orientation = (orientation) ? 0 : 180 + orientation;
    $('body').css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg)",           //Chrome
        "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg)",              //Firefox
        "-o-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg)",                //Opera
        "-ms-transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg)",               //IE's novos
        "transform": "rotate(" + new_orientation + "deg)",                   //nativa
        "filter": "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3)" //IE's antigos
    });
});
```

Ao invés de atribuir o evento ao "orientationchange" você pode optar também por usar o evento "resize" também funciona.

## Referência:

- [Resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7010010/2319589)
- créditos a a resposta do  **@OnoSendai** pelo filter do IE antigo que eu havia esquecido :P

Comment: Grande @PauloRoberto, cara não funcionou aqui no meu código :(, vc por acaso tem um exemplo funcional ai?

Answer (score 0):

Uma solução é um aviso para o usuário deixar o dispositivo em modo retrato.

Crie uma div position: fixed que cobre todo o conteúdo da página, e coloque um aviso dizendo que o site só é exibido corretamente em modo retrato. Após isso, use o seguinte código CSS para mostrar/ocultar:

```
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
#aviso { display:none; }
}

@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
#aviso  { display:block; }
}
```

Usei esse método em um projeto recente, e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: "Meio" agressivo esse método, né?

Comment: Bem, eu queria fazer o mesmo que você, deixar a tela travada, mas não achei outro método, só esse.

Comment: Legal @DianCarlos, mas estou com um problema ao usar esses orientation.. quando tem um input e sobe o teclado e trata como se fosse em formato paisagem e dai some tudo.